# Wordpress Custom Query with Custom Taxonomies - Pagination Bug

Tags: php, wordpress, url, pagination, taxonomy

I've created a custom query with multiple taxonomies involved, and on top of that I use `paginate_links`
to have pagination in place. Taxonomies are being selected by drop-down select forms using `onchange="this.form.submit()"` to be able to filter posts and which is only a temporary solution but works fine for now, and worth noting for the sake of this case.

Pagination works fine, posts are being displayed correctly when taxonomy terms selected, however when I leave the first page and let's say I go to page #2 and I select a different taxonomy-term in the drop-down selector, the URL keeps the current page number, and adds the selector ID to it. Whereas what I would like to achive is when I click on a different taxonomy in the selector, the newly selected taxonomy query creates a new URL to start from the first page of that certain taxonomy.

Let me bring up an example to be more clear of what I mean above:

1. I select taxonomy term "brand1" from the brand selector to display all posts related to that taxonomy term

[image]

URL at this point is `mydomainname.com/?brandselector=brand1` and so far so good.

2. I go to page number #2 via the pagination, now the URL looks like this:
   `mydomainname.com/page/2/?brandselector=brand1`
3. ***The issue itself starts here:*** I click on a different taxonomy-term in any of the drop down selectors as shown below:

[image]

Now I either get an empty page if the taxonomy-term doesn't have enough posts to reach multiple pages of pagination, or I see lists of posts right from page 2 or whichever else number I was on before, of the newly selected taxonomy term.

URL now looks like this:
`mydomainname.com/page/2/?brandselector=brand2`

So the page number is not being reset on a newly selected taxonomy-term.

My code:

```
    global $wpdb, $post, $page;
    
    echo "<div class='entry-content'>";
    
    echo '<div class="filter-box">';
    
    echo '<form name="selectbrand" method="GET" style="width:200px;">';
    echo '<select id="brandselector" name="brandselector" onchange="this.form.submit()">';
      echo '<option value="">Select brand:</option>';
        $brands = get_terms(array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'brand',
                        'hide_empty' => true,
                        'orderby' => 'name',
                    ) );
       
    foreach ( $brands as $brand ) { ?>
    <?php echo '<option value="' . $brand->slug . '">' . $brand->name . '</option>';
            };
            echo '</select>';
            echo '</form>';
    
    echo '<form name="selectdrive" method="GET" style="width:200px;">';
    echo '<select id="driveselector" name="driveselector" onchange="this.form.submit()">';
      echo '<option value="">Select drive:</option>';
        $drives = get_terms(array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'drive_cat',
                        'hide_empty' => true,
                        'orderby' => 'name',
                    ) );
       
    foreach ( $drives as $drive ) { ?>
    <?php echo '<option value="' . $drive->slug . '">' . $drive->name . '</option>';
            };
            echo '</select>';
            echo '</form>';
            
    echo '</div>'; //filter-box
    
    
    if ( !empty( $_GET['driveselector'])){
        $term_id = $_GET['driveselector'];
        }
    
    
    if ( !empty( $_GET['brandselector'])){
        $term_id = $_GET['brandselector'];
        }
     
     //<-----------------<<<<Main Query start>>>>---------------------
       
       $main_args = array(
                'post_type'=> 'things',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order'   => 'DESC',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'paged' => $page,
    );
    
     //<-----------------<<<<Main Query + Custom Query>>>>---------------------
    
    $taxquery = array();
    
    if ( !empty($term_id) || isset($term_id) ) {
        array_push($taxquery,array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'brand',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term_id
                ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'drive_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term_id
                )
            ));
    }
    
    if(!empty($taxquery)){
        $main_args['tax_query'] = $taxquery;
    }
    
    global $main_query;
    $main_query = new WP_Query( $main_args );

'<div class="content-box">';

  if ( $main_query->have_posts() ) :
   while ( $main_query->have_posts() ) : $main_query->the_post();

  //content start here
```

And the pagination:

```
//<!-- end blog posts -->

endwhile;

echo '<div class="pagination">';
$total_pages = $main_query->max_num_pages;
if ($total_pages > 1){
    $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('page'));
       echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => preg_replace('/\?.*/', '/', get_pagenum_link(1)) . '%_%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
}    
echo '</div>';

wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

What do I missing to reset URL when clicked on a different taxonomy-term? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, and sorry if I used certain technical terms wrong, I'm still learning. Thanks.

Comment: I would switch paginate_links over to using query strings for page numbers, and then it is much easier to reset in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not defining an `action` attribute to the `form` element, the default action is to go to the current url. So once you use the pagination hyperlink, next time the form will send the request to that link. Setting the action attribute will fix this.

```
echo '<form action="/" name="selectdrive" method="GET" style="width:200px;">';
```